# Xamarin - Error while try to downloadString from SSL websites (WebClient)

Tags: ios, ssl, xamarin.ios, xamarin, webclient

I have an iOS application that developed by Xamarin Studio.
When I try to get a string from server I got the following exception.

```
Exception in Class: WebClient 
Line : 271 
and Method:DownloadDataCore 
with message Error: SendFailure (Error writing headers) 
 Stack Trace:  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00065] in ///Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/8.2.0.207/src/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:971 
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse () [0x0000e] in ///Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/8.2.0.207/src/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:985 
  at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse (System.Net.WebRequest request) [0x00000] in ///Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/8.2.0.207/src/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebClient.cs:1563 
  at System.Net.WebClient.ReadAll (System.Net.WebRequest request, System.Object userToken) [0x00000] in ///Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/8.2.0.207/src/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebClient.cs:972 
  at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataCore (System.Uri address, System.Object userToken) [0x0000a] in ///Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/8.2.0.207/src/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebClient.cs:271
```

When I try to download the string from a none-SSL website it is ok and loads the string without any problem.

The website certificate is completely valid and It doesn't refused by Safari both in simulator and OSX.

I am runing the application on simulator.

I will be so thankful if you can help me fix the issue.

The code that I used for getting string from server is :

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (o, certificate, chain, errors) => true;
WebClient wc = new WebClient ();
wc.CachePolicy = new System.Net.Cache.RequestCachePolicy (System.Net.Cache.RequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore );
result =  wc.DownloadString (Url);
```

Regards

Comment: It might be a server that does not accept TLS 1.0 (or SSL 3). Can you give us the URL you're trying to access ?

Comment: @poupou I'm so sorry unfortunately I can't share the link here , Please let me know which information from my website's certification do you need to help me fix the issue ? I will share it here. Thank you so much

Comment: It's not about your certificate, but how your server is set up. Ensure it accept TLS **1.0** connections (e.g. using other software).

Comment: @poupou This is the protocols test result of server : 
Protocols
TLS 1.2 Yes
TLS 1.1 No
TLS 1.0 No
SSL 3 No
SSL 2 No

Answer (score 0):

Before accessing SSL site with mono, you have to run `mozroots --import --sync` to import list of mozilla trusted certificates.

Also, there is [mono security FAQ](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/faq/security/) which can help to resolve SSL issues.

Comment: Thank you for answer , But this command does not fixed the issue , I tested it yesterday

Comment: This command won't help for iOS, in part because it cannot be run on devices. So the Xamarin.iOS product verify the certificates using iOS API (so it will always give the same result as the OS itself).